# Вложенный цикл for * for

Tags: java, for

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {  
     for (int j = 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        System.out.print(i);     
     }    
}
```

Почему результат: 0011. А не 0110?

Answer (score 3):

В первой итерации внешнего цикла i=0, цикл входит во внутренний цикл, где он проходит 2 раза (j>=0) с этим значением i. Дальше происходит выход из внутреннего цикла и i присваивается значение 1 и все повторяется.